# numpy is not installing in Pycharm. Need experts to help me out

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I tried using GUI of pycharm. I went to
Settings>Interpreter>add(+)

I installed numpy using pip install numpy in my CMD. It installs successfully but I it is not showing in
my pycharm interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

If you created a project in Pycharm with default settings, it will create a virtual enviroment for your spesific project. To install Numpy you can simply click on "File -> Settings -> Project: Project Name -> Project Interpreter and press the "+" icon. Search for Numpy and click on "install package"